# java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, socketexception

I made an app that works on android 2.2
but will be used on android 2.3
and when I started the app with 2.3 emulator I got this exception message.

How to fix it?

```
12-22 14:09:17.820: I/ActivityManager(60): Start proc com.myteam for activity com.myteam/.ui.MijnTeamMain: pid=623 uid=10038 gids={3003, 1015}
12-22 14:09:18.660: D/dalvikvm(623): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 57K, 49% free 2767K/5379K, external 2041K/2137K, paused 40ms
12-22 14:09:27.635: W/ActivityManager(60): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-22 14:09:28.124: W/ActivityManager(60): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{406cae40 com.myteam/.ui.MijnTeamMain}
12-22 14:09:28.685: D/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
12-22 14:09:33.259: D/dalvikvm(310): GC_EXPLICIT freed 741K, 49% free 3363K/6535K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 90ms
12-22 14:09:38.389: D/dalvikvm(272): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 52% free 2776K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 107ms
12-22 14:09:43.380: D/dalvikvm(354): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 48% free 3523K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 66ms
12-22 14:09:48.470: D/dalvikvm(234): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 51% free 2724K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 86ms
```

Comment: may be Internet connection error

Comment: No, this is not Internet connection , if try on 2.2 simulator there isn't problem, all si ok, but if run on 2.3.3 simulator show this message in logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get this exception in the emulator.
It is nothing to worry about, just a bug in the emulator, I think.

It probably has nothing to do with the app you are developing.

Answer (score 0):

Sntp, is a time related protocol. I think the emulator is trying to fetch time and if your app is not doing that, you need not worry.